# Update Boolean Value in plist dictionary

Tags: objective-c, boolean, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to update a boolean value in a plist dictionary in an iphone app.  The plist dictionary contains several strings and two boolean values.  Below is my current code.

I first define the plist and then define the NSMutableDictionary.  When the third line of code below is run I get an error.

```
NSString *plistFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Property List" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistFile];

[[dict objectForKey:@"Day 1"] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"Bookmarked"];
```

The error highlights the return statement below with the following error  "Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    @autoreleasepool{   
     return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
     }
}
```

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because `dict` is mutable doesn't mean that it's sub dictionaries are. Also `NSMutableDictionary` has no `setBool:forKey:` method.

```
NSMutableDictionary *subDict = [[dict objectForKey:@"Day 1"] mutableCopy];
[subDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE] forKey:@"Bookmarked"];
[dict setObject:subDict forKey:@"Day 1"];
```

Comment: I added this new code in my button click event and the code is no longer crashing but the Day 1 Dictionary containing Bookmarked Boolean did not update to TRUE or YES.  I checked the plist while running the app and after closing the iphone simulator.

Comment: do not forget to autorelease the mutableCopy or you will leak it

Comment: @user1459279: are you sure the plist is overwritten after the dictionary update?

Comment: autorelease is an error with arc. The plist is not updated, only the dictionary, these are two seperate entities, one in memory and one on disk. You can't use [NSBundle mainBundle] to save data, just to access it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that I can't permanently modify a plist.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the values of a plist file as long as it doesn't reside in the bundle.

When you declare the Boolean property in the object, it needs to use the "BOOL" and not "Boolean".  This will cause errors when you save the file and try to read it again.